# How to execute the function when click on canvas_image in Tkinter without spoiling the GUI?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have a code that changes the image from `my_pic1` to `my_pic2` when the cursor hover on it and works fine but what should I do if I want to execute `on_click` function when the user click on the image (`my_pic1`) ?

```
from tkinter import * 

def on_click():
    print('clicked')

def onObjectClick1(event):
    canv.itemconfig(obj1, image=my_pic2)
    canv.tag_bind(obj1, '<Leave>', onObjectClick2)     

def onObjectClick2(event):
    canv.itemconfig(obj1, image=my_pic1)
    canv.tag_bind(obj1, '<Enter>', onObjectClick1)        
    
root = Tk()    
canv = Canvas(root, width=300, height=300)

background = PhotoImage(file="background.gif")
canv.create_image(300,300,image=background)

my_pic1 = PhotoImage(file="start000-before.png")
my_pic2 = PhotoImage(file="start000-after.png")

obj1 = canv.create_image(50,50,image=my_pic1, anchor=NW)
canv.tag_bind(obj1, '<Enter>', onObjectClick1)        
canv.tag_bind(obj1, '<Leave>', onObjectClick2)        
canv.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I have used `Button` but it's giving the image background in white color which is spoiling the look and feel of the GUI.

This is my code after adding button,

```
from tkinter import * 

def on_click():
    print('clicked')

root = Tk()    

canv = Canvas(root, width=300, height=300)
canv.pack()

background = PhotoImage(file="background.gif")
canv.create_image(300,300,image=background)

my_pic1 = PhotoImage(file="start000-before.png")
my_pic2 = PhotoImage(file="start000-after.png")

btn = Button(canv, image=my_pic1, command=on_click)
btn.bind('<Enter>', lambda e: btn.config(image=my_pic2))        
btn.bind('<Leave>', lambda e: btn.config(image=my_pic1))        

canv.create_window(50, 50, window=btn, anchor=NW)

root.mainloop()
```

I'm very noob in Tkinter! Please help me!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event for a left click is "<1>", so:

```
from tkinter import *

def on_click(event=None): # add the event parameter
    print('clicked')

def onObjectClick1(event=None):
    canv.itemconfig(obj1, image=my_pic2)

def onObjectClick2(event=None):
    canv.itemconfig(obj1, image=my_pic1)

root = Tk()
canv = Canvas(root, width=300, height=300)

background = PhotoImage(file="background.gif")
canv.create_image(300,300,image=background)
my_pic1 = PhotoImage(file="start000-before.png")
my_pic2 = PhotoImage(file="start000-after.png")

obj1 = canv.create_image(50,50,image=my_pic1, anchor=NW)
canv.tag_bind(obj1, '<Enter>', onObjectClick1)
canv.tag_bind(obj1, '<Leave>', onObjectClick2)
canv.tag_bind(obj1, '<1>', on_click)
canv.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I didn't get it ? `'<1>'` what does it do ?

Comment: Just like the event "<Enter>" runs the onObjectClick1 function when the mouse hovers, the event "<1>" will run the on_click function.

Comment: @sodmzs1 - `1` is shorthand for `Button-1` .. ie `Left Click`.  This will probably not fix your problem, though. When you click it will switch quickly to whatever colors you have set for the 'active' state. A potentially better way would be to use `ttk` and `map` images to each button state.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick solution! But now it's showing me this error `TypeError: on_click() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given`

Comment: That error is because you didn't include the `event` argument like you did for your other functions. Answer edited to show the standard way.

Comment: @MichaelGuidry it works fine for the canvas object; I tested it before posting.

Comment: Oh my bad! :D Thank you so muchhhh!!!!!!!!! You saved my life! It's working now!